# Capturing payment; express checkout

Tags: paypal, capture, payment

Hi 
I have paypal express checkout working on my site, when user buys something the transaction goes through and the merchant is able to capture payment by clicking on the capture button on the sandbox site. Problem is that I need 'capture status' returned to the site as I need to store it in database for future use, is there a way that paypal sends some notification whenever the payment is captured by the merchant.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PayPal IPN: https://www.paypal.com/ipn

In short, include NOTIFYURL in your SetExpressCheckout and DoExpresscheckoutPayment call and you'll receive a POST on that URL when the transaction has been captured. Look for 'PAYMENTSTATUS', as that should read 'Complete'.

Don't forget to validate the POST by sending it back to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_notify-validate and checking for a VERIFIED / INVALID response.